# Fill a date-filled cell red if older than 30 days and no date paid entered in another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I have two cells in Excel that are for dates (date billed and date paid). I need the date billed cell (say A1) to fill red **if** it contains a date **and** that date is older than 30 days **and** nothing has been entered in the date paid cell (say B1).

Once I enter a date in the date paid cell (B1) then the color should disappear.

Does anyone know how I could do that?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this:

```
=((TODAY()-A1)>30)*(B1="")*(A1<>"")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional formatting, "use a formula to decide which cell to format":

`=AND(A1<TODAY()-30,B1="")`

**Update based on comment:**

`=OR(AND(A1<TODAY()-30,B1=""),A1="")`

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Can I ask if there's a way to add that A1 must have a date in it also? Meaning the above conditional formatting is filling red for any cell in column A that doesn't have any date in it also.

Comment: I'm so sorry. My comment didn't make sense and you answered based on the last sentence which is totally understandable. What I meant to say was I only want A1 t fill red if there is a date in it and that date is over 30 days old. So sorry.

Comment: I still don't understand. Do you mean you want to apply conditional formatting only to column A, and not column B? If yes, then just select only column A when you set the formatting.